# How to Write a Selection Criteria Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report, selection, criteria

I am new to Crystal Rpts...I am using crystal 13 on a windows 7 pro 64-bit.  I am trying to write a selection criteria formula for a basic report. Here is what I am trying to say..

if the status.temp_date is empty (null) but the status.perm_date has a date (not null)

then pull all records where that status.perm_date is < the projectedstatus.projected_date and a status.perm_date is in a date range for the projectedstatus.projected_date (projectedstatus.projected_date{?start date} to projectedstatus.projected_date {?end date})

also pull

all records with a projectedstatus.projected_date that is between the projectedstatus.projected_date {?start date} and projectedstatus.projected_date {?end date}

here is what I wrote:

```
(isnull({status.temp_date}) and not isnull({status.perm_date}) and 
{status.perm_date} < {projectedstatus.projected_date} and 
{projectedstatus.projected_date} in {?sdate} to {?edate}
```

this is only returning records with perm.date ....no currently active records with no perm.date and a projected.dates with in the selected date range

so then I tried:

```
if(isnull({status.temp_date})) and not isnull({status.perm_date}) then 
{status.perm_date} < {projectedstatus.projected_date} and 
{projectedstatus.projected_date } in {?sdate} to {?edate} and

if (isnull({status.temp_date})) and isnull({status.perm_date}) and not isnull 
({projectedstatus.projected_date}) then 

{projectedstatus.projected_date} in {?sdate} to {?edate}
```

now I'm not getting any records.....

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have used crystal reports long back, Selection formula what ever is written gets checked for each row and if the expression you wrote results in true then that record gets included. if returns false then that record will not be included.

from your code snippet you have to use the if else if conditions so that every condition is getting handled one single boolean true or false should result from there

one more way you can do is, if it is easy to write the the negative case where row should not come then , simply write that condition in if and return false also have else condition with return as true so that for all other conditions rows get selected

like example,

```
if ((isnull({temp.date}) and not isnull({perm.date}) and (( {perm.date} < {projected.date} and NOT  {projected.date}  in {?sdate} to {?edate}) OR ({perm.date} > {projected.date}))) then FALSE ELSE TRUE
```

Please check syntax once.